# Convert Ruby Array into average

Tags: ruby, arrays

Say I have an array as such:

```
array = [["male", 59], ["female", 31], ["unknown gender", 38]]
```

The number inside the array is the total number of users by gender. What I need to do is get each element of the array and find the average for each male, female and unknown and put them into a new array that looks like this:

```
new_array = [["male", 46], ["female", 24], ["unknown gender", 30]]
```

Where the 2nd value inside the tuple is the average.

I have tried setting it as such:

```
new_array = []
sum = 0
array.each do |k,v|
sum += v
new_array << [k,(v/sum)*100]
end
```

My new array however turns out to be `[["male", 100], ["female", 0], ["unknown gender", 0]]`

Ive tried a few different things and cannot figure out what Im doing wrong.  Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't see how you would get the second array from the first. Does the first actually have more subarrays?

Comment: I added an edit above, the numbers inside the first array are the total number of users by gender, I need to create a new array with the average % of the demographics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

The first is that you are doing integer division at `(v/sum)`. The result of this is probably not what you expect, so you should turn `v` into a float: `(v.to_f/sum)`.

The second problem is that you are using the `sum` variable before it *actually contains the sum*.

Putting these two together:

```
array = [["male", 59], ["female", 31], ["unknown gender", 38]] 
new_array = []
sum = 0
# calculating sum before it's used in division below.
array.each { |_, v| sum += v }

array.each do |k, v|
  new_array << [k, ((v.to_f / sum) * 100).round]
end
# => [["male", 46], ["female", 24], ["unknown gender", 30]]
```

Comment: Thats it, thank you.  My goal was trying to make this into a single iteration, Im learning about Big O notation so Im trying to write this in the best possible way, unfortunately it looks like there was no other way then creating 2 separate iterations.  Thank you again.

Comment: Iteration two times over the same array means `O(2n)`. What is still in `O(n)` complexity. That is fine, especially because it is unlikely that a list of genders will get huge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few things.  what is happening now is that sum is 59.  v/59 is one on the first iteration.  On the second iteration 31/90 == 0 because you are not dividing the sum by the number of iterations.  What you really want is 31/45 because 45 is 90/2(2 being the number of iterations)

1) you need to divide the sum by the number of iterations to get the current average.

2) your syntax of

```
array.each do |k,v|
```

is misleading because you are not dealing with keys and values but with array indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use more specialised Ruby methods like `inject` or `map` instead of the simple `each`:

```
array = [['male', 59], ['female', 31], ['unknown gender', 38]] 

total = array.inject(0) { |sum, (_, n)| sum + n }

new_array = array.map { |k, v| [k, ((v.to_f / total) * 100).round] }
#=> [["male", 46], ["female", 24], ["unknown gender", 30]]
```

Furthermore the `((v.to_f / total) * 100).round` part can be extracted into its own method like this:

```
def percentage(value, total)
  ((value.to_f / total) * 100).round
end
```

What makes the `map` more readable:

```
new_array = array.map { |k, v| [k, percentage(v, total)] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice, I suggest you consider using hashes rather than an arrays and symbols rather than strings:

```
hash = { male: 59, female: 31, unknown_gender: 38 }
  #=> {:male=>59, :female=>31, :unknown_gender=>38}
tot = hash.values.reduce(:+)
  #=> 128
percents = hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = (100.0*v/tot).round }
  #=> {:male=>46, :female=>24, :unknown_gender=>30}
```